# Show and hide the text field in the same row for each checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, checkbox

In my jsp, I created dynamic check boxes from database.Now I want to show and hide the text field in the same row for each check box.tell me the possible ways.I was tried with some java script and jquery but text field comes only for the first check box.

```
 function Checkbox(){
       if(document.getElementById('select').checked){
         document.getElementById('test').style.display='block'; 
            document.getElementById('test1').style.display='block'; 
    }else{
          document.getElementById('test').style.display='none';
          document.getElementById('test1').style.display='none';
        }
 }   
  <table>
        <c:if test="${empty PAStranslist || PASEditValue == null}">
            <c:if test="${!empty assetsList}">
        <c:forEach items="${assetsList}" var="assetsList" varStatus="loop">  
                       <tr>
                        <td width="18%" class="thlabel"><c:out value='${assetsList.asset}'/></td>
                         <%-- <c:if test="${assetsList.selectedCheckBox == 'true'}"> --%>
                        <td width="32%"><form:checkbox path="selectedCheckBox" name ="select" value="${assetsList.id}"  id="select"  onclick="Checkbox();"/></td>
                        <td  width="18%" class="thlabel" style="display: none" id="test">Asset Code</td>
                        <td  width="32%" style="display: none" id="test1" ><form:input path="assetCode"  maxlength="20"   onkeyup="check(this, '20');"></form:input>
                         <%-- </c:if>  --%>


                    </tr> 
                </c:forEach>

            </c:if>

            <c:if test="${empty assetsList}">
                <tr><td style="color: red">No physical assets to display</td></tr>
            </c:if>
        </c:if>
        </table>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: can you show the code that you tried?

Comment: dear singhakash, please see the code in above what iam tried.and tell me the correct answer

Comment: i tried the code like in above.please verify that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `onclick` function to use the current object:

```
onclick="Checkbox(this);"
```

Then using native JavaScript, in your JS function, you can do:

```
function Checkbox(obj){
   if(obj.checked){
     obj.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td')[2].style.display='block'; 
        obj.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].style.display='block'; 
}else{
      obj.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td')[2].style.display='none';
      obj.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].style.display='none';
    }
```

}

Using JQuery, you can do:

```
function Checkbox(obj){
       if(obj.checked){
         $(obj).closest('tr').find('#test').show(); 
            $(obj).closest('tr').find('#test1').show();
    }else{
          $(obj).closest('tr').find('#test').hide();
          $(obj).closest('tr').find('#test1').hide();
        }
 }
```

Comment: thank you ArinCool the jquery code is working fine for me. thanks a lot

Comment: There is a `tick` below the arrows beside the answer. You need to mark it as green :)

Comment: just now iam tick it .now it as changed to green

Answer (score 0):

You need to uniquely identify each row of data in your forEach iterator, so you can reference each row separately.

Assign a unique ID based on the current row index, such as:

```
<td  width="32%" style="display: none" id="test1_<c:out value='${loop.index}'/>" >
```

Then change the javascript function to be:

```
function Checkbox(index){
       if(document.getElementById('select_'+index).checked){
         document.getElementById('test_'+index).style.display='block'; 
            document.getElementById('test1_'+index).style.display='block'; 
    }else{
          document.getElementById('test_'+index).style.display='none';
          document.getElementById('test1_'+index).style.display='none';
        }
 }
```

And your call to that function would become:

```
onclick="Checkbox('<c:out value="${loop.index}"/>');"
```

Comment: thank you Nicholas Smith i tried this one.and tell whether it works or not.i hope it is working